# Do lodash library methods help in improving performance?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I was going through lodash source code and found that a simple _.get method will execute more than 10 instructions to get the value of c in `{a: {b: {c: 10}}}` whereas i can simply access c by doing `!!a && !!b && a.b.c`.

The only improvement i can see between writing it my way and the lodash's `_get(obj, 'a.b.c')` is, lodash's code looks pretty.

Should I still be preferring lodash methods over js methods?

Comment: What if you wish to get `a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i.j.k.l.m.n.o`? How much items you will write manually? Sometimes you have to sacrifice speed for flexibility.

Comment: Yeah, in that case, I agree with the way lodash resolves things, but in most cases, objects that we want to access are not as nested. Mostly because, at the point where we actually use the innermost property of that very-very-nested-object, we will only have a part of it. Ex: in react, reducers only send selected part of application state, selectors further drill them down, further components distribute parts of state as props to child components etc. ultimately, there will be hardly three level nesting like in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Lodash is not for performance improvements. It's for doing things in a more convenient way or to use some ready solutions insteAd of writing them yourself (like `debounce` and `throttle` for instance, them being especially useful imo)

2) You can't reliably tell how much slower is Lodash without proper benchmarking. This is because of the way JS interpreter, browser, OS and even CPU and RAM work. You don't really know which assembly instructions are executed, how they are treated by CPU or weather they might be blocked by OS or something. Counting instructions is useless. You will have to read something on these topics to understand this better.

3) Before optimizing things it's more effective to find bottle necks first and to optimize just the things that happen often or many times in a row, like in loops or on frequent events like mouse moves. And the the time complexity of algorithms and how often different things are executed is generally more important than attempts to make tiny optimizations.

Comment: Originally Lodash was meant as a performance improvement over Underscore :-)